# Flickr API Callback Cancel operation C#

Tags: c#, callback, flickr

Currently we are using Flickr API for Cloud synchronization. While Synchronization, Flickr API is validating credentials. After Authenticating, Flickr API prompts a message along with "OK I will Authorize it" and "Cancel" buttons. On clicking "OK I will Authorize it" button Flickr callback is happening whereas the Flickr callback doesn't happen on clicking Cancel.

Any idea on why it's behaving this way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You are sending the wrong CallbackURL with your signature.
2. You didn't set up the CallbackURL/Application Type right in the Flickr app page.

To see the app info go to `https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/by/[YOUR_USER_NAME]` and see if you filled out the right info (including the type of app)

[image]